# Can I change the capacity in a camera flash light so it can support 14500 batteries?

Tags: capacitor

I have a Sigma 530DG Super and usually I would use 4 AA batteries with it (1.2/1.5V x 4 = 4.8/6V). Last night I was adventurous (and stupid) and I put in 4 14500 batteries (similar to AA batteries but made in lithium and can produce a higher voltage at 3.7V, so 3.7V x 4 = 14.8V). I did this because I imagine it would give the flash light a higher "recharge" speed (the gap between each time I can fire). I was able to turn a regular AA battery powered toothbrush into a super sonic toothbrush by changing the battery into 14500 battery, so I was guess my trick would work on the Sigma 530DG as well. Unfortunately it didn't, and it burnt the capacitor in the flash light. See the picture below:

[image: burnt capacitor in Sigma 530DG]

Now the capacitor says "100 10m" on top, so it's a 10V 100uF capacitor. My understanding (based on my vague memory from college) this means it can take as much as 10V and releases 100uF when fired. So my question being, if I simply change the capacitor to something like 20V 100uF, would it work the same but with the added support for 14500 batteries? - Meaning now it would work with both AA batteries and 14500 batteries.

Comment: No. It's almost guaranteed that none of the other circuitry in your device is designed to support that voltage. You would have to replace quite a few other parts, to the point where its probably not worth it.

Comment: There's a 220u/10V aluminum electrolytic capacitor too *(right next to the orange cable)*. You and we don't know the rest of the circuitry. Maybe there's an IC having an absolute maximum input voltage of 8V. Who knows? It's impossible to say if it is safe to only replace the tantalum capacitor. By the way, BeB00 is right. You may need to replace some other components, too.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Not just replace but quite possibly redesign the core circuit.

Comment: 2x3.9V after resting from charger would have been safe but perhaps a bit hotter FET. Change both caps. Or as required.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 LiIon cells retain full 4.2V terminal voltage for weeks (months?) after a full charge. But quite likely safe.

Comment: TY Russ.  Yes the better battery test is use a quick pulse or small load to deplete quickly <<1% Ah to the resting voltage . Lead acid are similar but more leaky above 12.6 so resume faster from 14.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the schematic of the board from a [Russian website](https://impulsite.ru/viewtopic.php?t=160&p=10974):

[image]

***NOTE:** Designators may not match the ones on the actual circuit.*

The input voltage is applied to IC6 (an LDO) and IC1 (a step-up DC/DC controller). Abs. max input voltage for the LDO is 18V which is quite acceptable. But **abs. max input voltage for the Step-up DC/DC controller is 10V**. Most likely the IC is damaged.

You should never apply more than 10VDC. But technically, the whole circuit is designed for 6-7VDC input voltage.

Comment: Nice find. Useful page.

Answer (score 1):

> ... if I simply change the capacitor to something like 20V 100UF, would it work the same but with the added support for 14500 batteries?

No!
In fact no no no no no !!! :-) :-(.

The circuit will (hopefully) be designed to operate with a margin of safety on the maximum voltage of 4 x series AA Alkaline cells. This is about 4 x 1.65 = 6.6V.

A nominal 3.7V LiIon cell has a fully charged terminal voltage of 4.2V.
So 4 in series = 16.8V.
Two in series = 8.4V.

If the flash is otherwise undamaged it MAY operate with 2 x LiIon cells at 8.4V.
This is 8.4V / 6.6V = 27% more than the flash will nominally ever see when using 4 x Alkaline AA cells - so it MAY survive, and may not.

As well as the capacitor there is probably a power supply IC (or several) and transistors (probably safe), plus the inductor design current will depend on the supply voltage being in the correct range.

re

> Last night I was adventurous (and stupid)

Sadly that's closer to stupid (adventurous).
Increasing maximum voltage by a factor of 4.2 V / 1.65V = 2.5:1 should be expected to almost certainly cause problems, and/or damage. The toothbrush success may be due to use of a transistor only power oscillator and more than usual good luck.

---

If you have not damaged the flash beyond repair you may wish to riosk trying it with 2 x LiIon cells. An AA Alkaline will typically provide around 10A on short circuit when new, falling to under 5A quite quickly. Depending on model used, 2 x 14500 LiIon cells may provide a better overall result - and, as above, may damage the flash.